pybind11 bindings throwing exit code 139 (11:SIGSEGV) when accessing a struct member variable
I'm getting a segfault - Python exit code 139 (11:SIGSEGV) - when attempting to access a struct member variable. The struct looks like:
struct PlannerResult {
  std::vector<Node> route;
  double cost{0};
  double max_range{0};
  double speed{0};
};

The Node class looks like:
struct Node {
  Node(Charger* charger) : charger(charger) {};

  Charger* charger{nullptr};

  double duration{0};
  double arrival_range{0};
  double departure_range{0}; 

  bool visited{false};
  double cost{std::numeric_limits<double>::max()};
  Node* parent{nullptr};

  const std::string& name() const { 
    return ( charger ) ? charger->name : default_name_; }

  private:
    std::string default_name_{"NULL"};
};

And the python bindings for these two classes look like:
py::class_<PlannerResult>(m, "PlannerResult")
  .def_readwrite("route", &PlannerResult::route)
  .def_readwrite("cost", &PlannerResult::cost)
  .def_readwrite("max_range", &PlannerResult::max_range)
  .def_readwrite("speed", &PlannerResult::speed);

py::class_<Node>(m, "Node")
  .def(py::init<Charger*>(), py::arg("charger"))
  .def_readwrite("charger", &Node::charger)
  .def_readwrite("duration", &Node::duration)
  .def_readwrite("arrival_range", &Node::arrival_range)
  .def_readwrite("departure_range", &Node::departure_range)
  .def_readwrite("visited", &Node::visited)
  .def_readwrite("cost", &Node::cost)
  .def_readwrite("parent", &Node::parent)
  .def_property_readonly("name", &Node::name)

Finally, the line that's segfaulting on the python side looks like:
def update_planner_result(result: PlannerResult,
                          durations: Sequence[float]) -> PlannerResult:
    updated_result = result
    for idx, (node, duration) in (
            enumerate(zip(updated_result.route[1:], durations))):
        # This line below segfaults.
        prev_node = updated_result.route[idx]

       # do more stuff here...

My initial thought was that this has to do with pybind11's chosen "return value policy". The default return value policy for def_property and def_readwrite is py::return_value_policy::reference_internal.
So I tried other options including py::return_value_policy::reference and py::return_value_policy::copy, but neither of these solved the problem.
I'm not sure what to try next, and looking for some help from some pybind11 experts. Maybe this has something to do with the fact that the Node struct has raw pointer members?

What's Charger and why is it passed as raw ptr? Your Node have implicitly generated copy ctor and assignment, is it what you want? Do you need all of these costs, durations, ranges etc. to reproduce the problem?

"not sure what to try next" -- create a proper [mcve], then [edit] your question to included it. Currently, there's a lot of irrelevant things, yet many key parts are missing to let us reproduce the issue.

@DanMašek thanks for the feedback - it's my first time posting to SO, so I appreciate the link and the advice. I'll update my question soon.

No problem :) Probably the best option is to make a single c++ file for an executable, that embeds the interpreter (as well as your module) and executes a string containing the Python code required to reproduce the issue. Second best is a standalone cpp implementing the shared library (the binary Python module), and a Python script that imports it and reproduces the issue. (Sometimes the former is easier to run in debugger to catch issues). | Keep whittling that down to the absolute minimum. It's not only useful to improve your question, it teaches you how to debug.

Also provide information about the Python version, pybind11 version, compiler, OS.
